# How can i use gantry object in chronoform?

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to add css and js file in head. But my template is using gantry. So I need to use gantry object to add css and js. But this object is not accessible in my custom form code. I think my requireonce function can not include the file.

```
require_once('../../../../templates/rt_graffito/lib/gantry/gantry.php');
$gantry->init();
$gantry->addStyle('media/moo_rainbow/css/mooRainbow.css', 5);
$gantry->addScript('media/moo_rainbow/js/mooRainbow.js');
```

This is the code I am using in my chrono form. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you can use core Joomla `document` object and gantry shall pick it up, try follow:

```
<?php
 // ... some code here
 $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
 $document->addScript('media/moo_rainbow/js/mooRainbow.js');
 $document->addStyleSheet( 'media/moo_rainbow/css/mooRainbow.css');
 // ... other code
```

and documentation reference

http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addStyleSheet
http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

Comment: Yes, that's the possible way. But I have tried that already. It's including the file above all other files added using gantry object.
If I use gantry object then the files can be added after other usefull  mootools and jquery files which are dependencies for my custom js files

Comment: got your point, though never had order issues with document before. what exactly does not work with your try, if it returns any errors or something like this?

Comment: I have doubts that to use gantry includes your source files has to be into template appropriate folders, so no outside template includes, but check this guess